# Loopback - ACL - Default Role not working when Custom roles are enabled

Tags: node.js, acl, loopbackjs

I have few custom roles like "1"-->'Super Admin', "2"-->'TeamMember'...  I am maintaining my ACL list in Database and not in JSON.

**Use Case:**
- In Logged in case, If a SuperAdmin is in, he can use models as defined in ACL list. Working fine.
- Also, working fine with teamMember role.

- But, in unauthentiated case, neither any SuperAdmin/teamMember role(for example: Login page API), then the login API call is not succeeding, it is always 'pending'. Call not getting completed with either error/success. In this case, i want `$everyone` role to be processed. I have written `$everyone` with `ROLE` as `ALLOW` in ACL table properly.

ACL's were not getting searched.

The DEBUG list:

```
loopback:security:role isInRole(): $everyone +0ms
loopback:security:access-context ---AccessContext--- +0ms
loopback:security:access-context principals: [] +0ms
loopback:security:access-context modelName user +0ms
loopback:security:access-context modelId undefined +0ms
loopback:security:access-context property loginUser +0ms
loopback:security:access-context method loginUser +0ms
loopback:security:access-context accessType EXECUTE +0ms
loopback:security:access-context accessToken: +0ms
loopback:security:access-context   id "$anonymous" +0ms
loopback:security:access-context   ttl 1209600 +0ms
loopback:security:access-context getUserId() null +0ms
loopback:security:access-context isAuthenticated() false +0ms
loopback:security:role Custom resolver found for role $everyone +0ms
```

Role-Resolver:

```
//SUPER ADMIN
Role.registerResolver("1", function(role, context, cb) {
    let isSuperAdmin = false;
        app.models.RoleMapping.findOne({where: {principalId: userId}}, function(err, res){ //userId will be passed from other obj...it will be not null...here i just made it simple
            if(res.roleId == "1")
                isSuperAdmin = true;
            return cb(null, isSuperAdmin);
        });
});
```

***I could not able to login to my application due to this.***
I am extending the default User model and written a remoteMethod 'loginUser'to perform user login. (Even the default 'login'remote method is not working in this case)

***However, if i remove the role-resolver script, then no issue is faced. The login is successful***, with API returning success token. The issue i seem is only with the resolver,but unable to find the issue. Please help me to solve this issue.

**ACLS for my extended model `user` :** (for SuperAdmin and everyone)

`Col Names: id, model, property, accessType, permission, principalType, principalId`

`Rows:      '1',  'user',  '*',  '*',  'ALLOW',  'ROLE',  '1'
            '2',  'user',  '*',  '*',  'ALLOW',  'ROLE',  '$everyone'`

The `principalType: '1'` in table implies superAdmin.

Comment: Can you post the `ACLs` you're using for the `User` model?

Comment: Hi icecream_hobbit, i have updated my question detaily with ACL list.

Comment: Are you saving 1 & 2 as numbers/integers or strings ?

Comment: I am storing them as strings in table and also validating as strings in script.